# Some values disappear when tab joined in a small terminal window

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Why does my code behave differently in differently sized windows? Some of the `\t0` sequences are not printed in a small terminal window:

```
values = (3, 3, 'Boss1_320', 1523712, 45056, 1, 1, 4096, 4096, 0, 0, 0, 4096, 40960, 102400)

print(*values, sep='\t')
#3  3   Boss1_320   1523712 45056   1   1   4096    4096    4096    40960   102400

print(*values, sep='\t')
#3  3   Boss1_320   1523712 45056   1   1   4096    4096    0   0   0   4096    40960   102400
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this using IDLE, but weirdly enough this does happen on Powershell in Windows 10. It seems to be affected by the size of the terminal - everything printed out when it was long enough to fit the full string, but if the line has to wrap at one of the `0`s, then it just doesn't print that and goes to `4096`. The result of `join` looks unchanged, so it might have something to do with how the window handles `\t0`?

Comment: Interesting, can reproduce as well. The terminal must have some specific behaviour with these specific character sequences, but I have no idea what exactly…

Comment: @deceze Why did you edit "when run twice in a small Terminal window" into "differently sized windows" in the question? That seems to change the meaning of the sentence. It seems to be shriakhlic who brought up resizing the window, not OP. If "differently sized windows" is actually correct, then what size should the windows be exactly to reproduce the issue? FWIW, I can get related weird behaviour in Gnome Terminal, but not exactly the same.

Comment: FWIW, `print(*values, sep='\t')` is simpler and should be identical in behaviour